# Authentication issues with WCF - IP vs FQDN

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WPF app that talks to a WCF webservice.

One of my customers is having an issue where if I set the endpoint address to an ip address all works fine, but if I use a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) a security exception is thrown.

They have a very complicated network where the client communicates via 3G, through a web proxy and a checkpoint firewall to a web server.

They employed a consultant who discovered that an LDAP query is taking place on port 389. This port is closed but the request via the ip ignores the failure and continues while the request by domain name throws an exception.

What is the difference between a request by ip and a request by domain name? Why does one work and the other fail?

The security exception thrown is:

The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Here is my client config settings:

```
    <binding 
      name="Windows_Binding" 
      closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
      openTimeout="00:01:00" 
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
      allowCookies="false" 
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
      maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
      messageEncoding="Text" 
      textEncoding="utf-8" 
      transferMode="Buffered" 
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas 
        maxDepth="2147483647" 
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security 
        mode="Transport">
        <transport 
          clientCredentialType="Windows" 
          proxyCredentialType="None" 
          realm=""/>
        <message 
          clientCredentialType="UserName" 
          algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Comment: Do you have the option of changing the service configuration / binding?  If so, does <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post the server binding?

This is a fairly common error in WCF security when using Windows Security.
A couple of things to check

Check if the web server has the correct SPN created, since it works by IP Address and it fails by FQDN, it could mean that you don't have the SPN for the FQDN (a common thing) and also, you may have several host headers for the same IP Address on IIS.

Another thing you can try, it really sucks but it works:

Change your binding configuration to use CredentialType="Ntlm" and on IIS go to integrated authentication, providers and remove negotiate and leave only NTLM

Hope this helps

Comment: clientCredentialType="Ntlm" fixed the propblem. I'm guessing that the server was somehow preventing a fallback to Ntlm but specifying Ntlm directly works.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two different protocols that can be used for Windows authentication: The more modern Kerberos and the legacy NTLMv2. While Kerberos is more modern, it requires some more metadata to be available to work. NTLMv2 is much more simple.

A guess (which really just is a guess) is that with the IP address the NTLMv2 protocol is used which works without the additional information queried for in that LDAP query. With a domain name Kerberos is used and fails when there is no connectivity to the LDAP (Active Directory?) server.

Comment: Interesting guess. I should be able to test this by changing the clientCredentialType from Windows to Ntlm. Will give it a go and report back.